# Time zone conversions in R

Tags: r

```
Group_data = rbind(gpx1,gpx2,gpx3,gpx4,gpx5,gpx6,gpx7,gpx8,gpx9,gpx10,gpx11)    
dtime = strptime(Group_data[, 11], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
timestamp=strftime(dtime, format='%H:%M:%S')
timestamp=as.data.frame(timestamp)    
Group_data[, 12]=timestamp    
POSIXCT_object=as.data.frame.POSIXct(timestamp, tz = "GMT")   
ConverttoEST = with_tz(POSIXCT_object,"EST")
```

I used the code above to convert my data, which is in GMT to EST. The code above was unsucessful, but I am unsure why. I know EST is 4 hours behind GMT. The code didn't change the values at all. What is missing from the code?

Comment: Can you please post example of your data: `head(Group_data )`

Comment: `attr(timestamp$timestampe, "tzone") <- "EST"`? (Use the variable name for the `POSIXct` object, not the data.frame).

Comment: I thought I did use the variable name, which is "timestamp" to create the POSIXct object. Can you epxlain further?